# (C#, .net 6) Why can't I extend the ModelStateDictionary?

Tags: .net, extension-methods, modelstate

I wanted to extend the ModelStateDictionary to add a simple ModelState.AddModelErrors() that accepts multiple errors at once.

I have created the following class:

```
    public static class ModelStateExtensions
    {
        public static void AddModelErrors(this ModelStateDictionary msd, List<string> errors)
        {
            foreach(var error in errors)
            {
                msd.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        public static void AddDuck(this ModelStateDictionary msd)
        {
            msd.AddModelError("duck", "quack");
        }
    }
```

I then attempt to call it in the controller like so:

```
if(errors.Any())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelErrors(errors);

            }
```

And get the following error message:

```
'ModelStateDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'AddModelErrors' and the best extension method overload 'ModelStateExtensions.AddModelErrors(ModelStateDictionary, List<string>)' requires a receiver of type 'ModelStateDictionary'
```

I have:

- Added a using statement with the proper namespace to the controller
- Compiled everything first
- The extension method is in the same project, so a project reference shouldn't be needed

Regardless, I think those would give me a different error message, right?

What does that error message mean? How is the receiver *not* of type ModelStateDictionary?

Comment: I have just tested it and found no issues. Perhaps, you are having some name conflicts. Try to rename your extension class. Also, that class has to be `static`.

Comment: If the extension class isn't found (tested by renaming namespaces and not updating the using statement) it gets me a different error message: ('ModelStateDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'AddModelErrors' and no accessible extension method 'AddModelErrors' accepting a first argument of type 'ModelStateDictionary' could be found)

So pretty sure it's not that

Comment: According to https://developerpublish.com/c-error-cs1929-0-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-1-and-the-best-extension-method-overload-2-requires-a-receiver-of-type-3/ it is possible that you are extending some other `ModelStateDictionary` than the one used in your controller. Could you upload your project or a minimal reproducible example somewhere?